# When can 'sorting the entries of a matrix in descending order' be used?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning linear algebra with a book. I was reading about eigendecomposition and this sentence, "By convention, we usually sort the entries of Λ in descending order." didn't make sense to me. Λ is a diagonal vector, so I guessed it meant ordering elements in the main diagonal in descending order. (am I right?) So I thought what it meant on non diagonal matrices. And if it was even possible. Is it?

Comment: I guess that $\Lambda$ is the sequence of eigenvalues, it makes sense to arrange them in descending order as You might see from the minimax theorem, in infinite dimensions they form a zerosequence under appropriate assumptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $$\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1& & 0\\ &\ddots\\ \\0& &\lambda_n\end{pmatrix}$$
is a diagonal matrix, then $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of this matrix and the corresponding linear operator. If we assume they are real ( as it would be the case when this operator is selfadjoint) it does make sense to arrange them in descending order, because then $$\lambda_{j+1}=\min_{v_1,...,v_j\in V}\max_{|v|=1\\(v,v_1)=...=(v,v_j)=0}(\Lambda v,v),0\leq j\leq n-1$$
for Your $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ equipped withe inner product $(.,.)$ and the induced norm $|.|$. This is known as the Courant-Fisher-MiniMax-principle. In infinite dimensions this still holds for compact selfadjoint operators and in this case the sequence $\{\lambda_j\}$ is a sequence turning to zero. But:To arrange the entries of an arbitrary matrix (with real entries) in descending order wouldn't make much sense, but would be possible.